# Ignore the rest of a function after asserting that a function is called in python

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, tdd, clean-architecture

In Python, we want to assert that a function is called when calling another function. However, we want to ignore the execution after calling the required function. This necessity appears when we don't know the rest of the function. The rest of the function that will be developed later may invoke an object from an external environment like a database gateway. The typical solution is to mock that object. However, when we are practising TDD, we may not figure out the rest of the function yet. Therefore, we need to ignore it.
Here is the function I want to be developed:

```
class A:
    def func(self):
        self.a()
        self.b() # the rest of the function that we do not develop yet and we want to ignore during the test because actually, we do not even know if there is actually a b function.`
```

The test function

```
def test_a_is_called_during_func():
    mocked_a = Mock()
    with patch("A.a", new= mocked_a):
        A().func()
    mocked_a.assert_called_once()
```

We need to add something to the test to ignore the `b()`, which improves designing our test and makes it self-contained without the need to return to this test if we add something to the function.

Comment: How did you manage to write `A.func()` with a call to `b()` if you are `"are practising TDD"`?

Comment: Sorry, I will correct the code. The code is not actually my actual code in python. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: I see you have made changes to your code snippets, but they only seem to be fixes to make it run. My comment stands. How is it possible for `A.func()` to have a call to `b()`? There should be a test somewhere which, once written, requires that call. If you no longer execute that call your test should be failing.

Comment: We did not actually develop b() yet. We do not even know if there is even a b(). I want to define my test incrementally. func may need to call b() later. However, we do not know b yet. Probably, will be a dependency injection.

Comment: Just remove the call to `b()` until a test calls it into being.

Comment: I wrote b() there to show the future of func(). I don't want to mock it after actually I define my test.

Comment: `"the future of func()"` means [You Ain't Gonna Need It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: I could improve my code by putting b() and mock before passing the next test. Later, I can refactor the b() name. However, this will break YAGNI.

Comment: Let me explain more that I may need it. For instance, b() will get something from a Gateway. I must return to the old test and mock b(). I don't want this. If there is a way to just ignore the rest of func() after assert that a() is called.

Comment: func() do not have b() when I define my test. I need it once I added another test.  Here, we should return to the old test and mock b(). I do not want to change my test. This breaks OCP.

Comment: You *can* cheat and have: `class A: def func(self): self.a()` for your original test and have: `class B(A): def func(self): super().func();self.b()` for your next test which requires the call the `b()`.

Comment: What I am searching for is a strategy that helps me respect OCP and YAGNI at the same time.

Comment: The strategy you are proposing works technically. However, I think we agree that it cannot be always doable. Mostly, I don't think it is a good approach because it will make the design harder to understand, which actually the purpose of what we are discussing here.

Comment: I prefer to return to isolate my calls and return to my tests instead of having non-necessary inheritances. By the way, this strategy breaks LSP.

Comment: Just for people who read these comments later. We are talking about SOLID principles. OPC (Open-Close Principale) LSP (Liskov-Substitution Principles).

Comment: *"In Python, we want to assert that a function is called when calling another function. However, we want to ignore the execution after calling the required function"* I don't think I'd actually do this, but you could make the mocked `A.a` throw some custom exception of your choice, and catch that in your test. Then nothing in `func` will execute after it calls `a()`. Not bulletproof, for example if `func` had a `try...except Exception` then it wouldn't work as intended.

Comment: @slothrop thank you. This will be a solution; we will have to test itself isolated from the rest of the class. But, why do you think that we do not want to do that?

Comment: Oh, I don't have an opinion on what you want to do :) Personally I wouldn't do it, because I'm fine with simply doing `def b(self): pass` in the class.

Comment: @slothrop the conversion is more about the strategy of developing you application with TDD respecting SOLID and KISS and YAGNI principles, rather than providing a technical solution.

Comment: Fair enough, I think you and I come from different philosophical principles here. I don't really buy into pure TDD.

Comment: @slothrop b() actually calls a gatekeeper or may be a Gateway. In the first place, it is an interface that is not configured. Therefore, once we configure that dependency, we need to ignore it. We need our test to be working regardless of the dependency configurations.

Comment: OK - I think having the mocked `A.a` throw an exception is indeed one solution to that?

Comment: @slothrop, it is an interesting question on how you test without breaking the dependency. Thank you for your discussing and your help. I hope we can discuss other stuff on another platform one day.

Comment: @slothrop yup agree on the solution. Just write it and I will mark it as accepted solution.

Comment: @slothrop do you want to write the answer, I do you want me to write it? sorry I don't have the reputation for chats yet.

Comment: No problem, I will do it shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to have the mocked version of method `a` throw some custom exception of your creation. Then, execution of `func` won't proceed beyond the call to `a`, and you can just catch the exception in your test. For example:

```
class AbortTestedFunctionException(Exception):
    pass


def test_a_is_called_during_func():
    mocked_a = Mock(side_effect=AbortTestedFunctionException())

    with patch("A.a", new=mocked_a):
        try:
            A().func()
        except AbortTestedFunctionException:
            pass
    mocked_a.assert_called_once()
```

This isn't bulletproof: it wouldn't work as intended if `func` did a blanket exception handling strategy with `try... except Exception`.

Comment: Thank you for writing the solution. I hope this will help other improving their tests.

Comment: we may right a conference paper on this if you are interesting?

Comment: Thanks for asking but I have to say no, with everything else on my plate!

Comment: I may write a conference on paper based on this conversation, so I need to ask for your permission :)

Comment: No problem, happy for you to use anything I've said here :)